# How would I stop a std::thread in a controlled manner

Tags: multithreading, c++17

I have a program where I start multiple, long running threads (such as a REST-API). On primed signals (e.g `SIGHUP`) I would like to be able to shut down all threads cleanly (by waiting for them to exit). Below follows some code from a [thispointer article](https://thispointer.com/c11-how-to-stop-or-terminate-a-thread/) that illustrated a good idea on how to do this

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

void threadFunction(std::future<void> futureObj)
{
     std::cout << "Thread Start" << std::endl;
     while (futureObj.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == 
 std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        std::cout << "Doing Some Work" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    }
    std::cout << "Thread End" << std::endl;

}
int main()
{

    // Create a std::promise object
    std::promise<void> exitSignal;

    //Fetch std::future object associated with promise
    std::future<void> futureObj = exitSignal.get_future();

    // Starting Thread & move the future object in lambda function by reference
    std::thread th(&threadFunction, std::move(futureObj));

    //Wait for 10 sec
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    std::cout << "Asking Thread to Stop" << std::endl;

    //Set the value in promise
    exitSignal.set_value();

    //Wait for thread to join
    th.join();

    std::cout << "Exiting Main Function" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, as one might have noticed this concept has a critical drawback: the `exitSignal` will have to be emitted before `th.join()` is called.

In a situation where one wants to listen to a signal, e.g using `signal(SIGHUP, callback)` this is of course impractical.

My question is: are there better concepts for shutting down multiple threads? How would I go about them? I think using a `promise` is not a bad idea, I just haven't found a way with it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::notify_all_at_thread_exit() on a std::condition_variable.
Here is an example:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

#include <cassert>
#include <string>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

bool ready = false;
std::string result; // some arbitrary type

void thread_func()
{
    thread_local std::string thread_local_data = "42";

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);

    // assign a value to result using thread_local data
    result = thread_local_data;
    ready = true;

    std::notify_all_at_thread_exit(cv, std::move(lk));

}   // 1. destroy thread_locals;
    // 2. unlock mutex;
    // 3. notify cv.

int main()
{
    std::thread t(thread_func);
    t.detach();

    // do other work
    // ...

    // wait for the detached thread
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, [] { return ready; });

    // result is ready and thread_local destructors have finished, no UB
    assert(result == "42");
}
```

Source: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/notify_all_at_thread_exit)